# Telegram API передача видео с сервера

Tags: python, flask, telegram, telebot

Как с помощью Python модуля Telebot и Flask можно реализовать передачу видео размером 500-1000мб без долгой загрузки на сервер телеграма в видео потокового видео с сервера, но так, чтобы это видео нельзя было загрузить или поделиться?

Comment: Никак. Абсолютно любое видео можно загрузить или поделиться им. А для преодоления долгой загрузки вам необходимо нарушить законы физики и превысить скорость света.

Answer (score 0):

Если видео уже имеется на видео-хостинге, то можно сделать например с помощью `parse_mode="Markdown"` и `[ ](URL)`

Пример:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Текст сообщения [ ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rb0UmrCXxVA)", parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Возможно, не самый лучший вариант, но все же. (В тексте будет невидимый символ, который содержит ссылку)